# How can I disable a JSF h:button?

Tags: jsf, button

Using JSF 2.2, it appears that the h:button does not support a "disabled" attribute like the commandButton does.  I've tried putting the disabled logic into the "outcome" attribute but that disables the button AND puts a label on the button along with a appended ":" plus message.

Is there a more obvious way to disable it?

Comment: Please state your jsf version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I can use the a pass-through attribute for this:

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:button a:disabled="#{empty bean.list}" ... />
```

I wonder if there is a better way though.

Comment: confirmed! (both the problem and the solution). Curious to why this is not in the default component. Keep in mind though that this is now a pure client-side solution and can be easily tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

A working hack that doesn't depend on JSF 2.2 like passthrough does:

```
<h:button value="Edit" outcome="#{(item.editable ? 'original_outcome' : '#')}" />
```

Even gives the button a nice disabled look, at least in my setup.

As with the passthrough example I think this can be trivially overridden on the client side so it is more of a usability feature than a security feature in its current form.